# Check nginx error log for 404 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

I am complete newbie. I have an nginx server up and running to host my Django app on Digital Ocean. My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app_name` has this:

```
location /static/ {
        root /opt/app_name;
    }
```

Which points to the right folder where all static files are corrected i.e. `/opt/app_name/static`

I am still getting `404` error for all static files. I also have a `/etc/nginx/sites-available/django` file that looks liek this:

```
# your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        root /opt/bizkeeda;
    }
```

I am still seeing all 404s for static files in the static folder. 
Now the **problem** is `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` is completely empty! How do I check from where nginx is trying to serve static files, so that I can correct it/

Comment: Those files need to symlinked to sites-enabled as well, assuming you're on a Debian-derived distribution.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did sym link it. ALthough just once. Do I need to do it again if I make any change to file?

Comment: No, but you do need to restart nginx.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did restart it. I cannot understand why it is not serving static files correctly. Is there a way to know from where nginx is trying to serve it?

Comment: Are you sure the links are pointing to the correct place in your HTML? What do your browser's dev tools say?

Comment: Adding another thing, that I just got to know. My working domain on DigitalOcean would be `www.domainname.com:8001` Is it the reason somehow? And my html points to static files like this: `    <link href="{%static "css/leaflet.css"%}"  rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Why is it running on port 8001? That sounds like you are accessing gunicorn directly, rather than going through nginx.

Comment: Yes it looks like. I am following Digital Ocean's guide to setup my django app on their droplet. That's how they have given in guide. What should I do?

Comment: Carry on to [step 10 of the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn#step-ten-configure-nginx) and configure nginx, then access your site without the port suffix.